# Facebook cache crawler keep showing old image as preview shared from a feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am having a strange behavior from Facebook Share Feed Dialog.

Why do i am keep getting a different preview image for the share feed from my app? I have generated dynamic watermarked image. But when I share this using facebook feed dialog, it keeps showing the old generated image? 
How long does Facebook cache crawler keeps the old image in its memory?

Can you please guide me whats I am messing with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long is Facebook caching the sharing thumbnails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845095/how-long-is-facebook-caching-the-sharing-thumbnails)

Comment: Its not about actually caching; its more about how to handle  it

Comment: Which is also answered in that question.